# Can I join a Minecraft world of my friend's, if my friend does not have Live gold?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-network

I wanna play with my friend, and he is in the same house as me to visit. I want to join his single-player Minecraft world, or he joins mine. It doesn't matter for us. I have a PC with Minecraft Windows 10 Edition, and he had an Xbox with Live Gold. It worked just fine when he had the Xbox Live gold, but now I want to know if I join **HIS** world, can I play with him, when **he** doesn't have Xbox Live gold?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play without him having live gold.

Answer (score 0):

**From the [Official Minecraft Support Site](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4410316619533-How-to-Play-Minecraft-Multiplayer):**

> ## Playing on a Local Area Network (LAN):
>
> This requires opening your home or local area network (LAN) to others who are also connected to that network. Here is how to connect for Minecraft for mobile devices, Nintendo Switch, PlayStation, Windows or Xbox.
>
> ### Before you start
>
> - Each player that wants to join must be connected to the same network.
> - The selected host device must be capable of running a server of the chosen world.
> - Everyone joining must run the same version of the game as the host.
>
> ### Start a LAN game
>
> - Create a new world or click the pencil icon to edit a current world.
> - Go to Multiplayer and make sure that Visible to LAN Players is enabled.
> - Choose Create or Play to start the world.
>
> ### Join a LAN game
>
> - Go to the Play
> - Click the Friends tab and look for available LAN Games.